# Combining multiple gradle zip tasks into a single one

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, zip, devops

I have a gradle task to zip the `.yaml` files into a zip folder, which looks like this:

```
task gradleTask1(type: Zip) {
    from 'src/test/resources/source_one/'
    include '**/*'
    archiveName 'file-collect.zip'
    destinationDir(file("${buildDir}/resources/test/staging/target_one"))
}
```

Similarly, I have other tasks that look the same, but the source and target directories are different.

```
task gradleTask2(type: Zip) {
    from 'src/test/resources/source_two/'
    include '**/*'
    archiveName 'file-collect.zip'
    destinationDir(file("${buildDir}/resources/test/staging/target_two"))
}

task gradleTask3(type: Zip) {
    from 'src/test/resources/source_three/'
    include '**/*'
    archiveName 'file-collect.zip'
    destinationDir(file("${buildDir}/resources/test/staging/target_three"))
}
```

And the main issue is I have to add dependency every time I add a new zip task as follows:

```
compileJava.finalizedBy gradleTask1

compileJava.finalizedBy gradleTask2

compileJava.finalizedBy gradleTask3
```

Is there any way I can achieve these steps dynamically? Can I have a single zip task (something like `zipAll`) and finally the task dependency can be

```
compileJava.finalizedBy zipAll
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following (example [here](https://github.com/codetojoy/gists_gradle/tree/main/stack_overflow_64377316)):

```
tasks.withType(Zip).all { task ->
    def taskName = task.name

    if (taskName ==~ /gradleTask.*/) {
        println "TRACER adding dependency on ${taskName}"
        compileJava.finalizedBy taskName
    }
}
```

This will dynamically find tasks of type `Zip` with name matching `gradleTask*` and add it to the list of tasks for `compileJava.finalizedBy`.

There is no `zipAll` task, but `gradle compileJava` will work as desired.